# Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS screen blank after regular system update - NOMODESET boot option doesn't resolve?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, nvidia

I had the blank screen / screen flicker issue today when running a usual system update on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS amd64. My PC is a Dell Latitude D620 with Nvidia Quadro NVS 110M graphics. Reading existing threads, I've tried via Grub the NOMODESET obit option but this hasn't helped. Can anyone please offer any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: did you install the nvidia driver yourself or did you use apt-get or the ubuntu software center to do that?

Comment: I used the Ubuntu software centre to install the Nvidia driver..

Comment: Can anyone help here? I'm a bit lost as to what to try next. I have a flickering screen that won't allow me to view easily. It is launching now in low res mode and i can get to Grub but the nomodeset makes no difference to the graphics on boot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this from tyy:

```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
    sudo bash
    grub-mkrescue
    update-grub
    update-grub2
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    sudo apt-get install -f
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I'm pretty inexperienced with Linux. How do I input those commands if I can't get or see a Terminal window..?

Comment: @NickW Can you login through the text-user-interface?

Comment: I can try that but not sure how I would do that if I can't see a screen...?